# Time provider library using type safe handler - like chrono CPP

Tags: c++, type-safety

I'm trying to develop a c++ library that provide two kind of times:

1. UTC time(self explainitory)
2. System time(time since the system has went on)

I have looked into the [`chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library in cpp and im trying to implement my library, more of the same like `chrono`. the implementation is very complicated for me right now.

I'll post the complete code I have later on, but so far I support only UTC time. I have few problems in my code that I want to improve but I don't know how exactly.

```
#include "atltime.h"
#include "mmsystem.h"

namespace tc{
    typedef struct date{
        unsigned int day;
        unsigned int month;
        unsigned year;

        date(unsigned int _day, unsigned int _month, unsigned int _year)
        {
            day = _day;
            month = _month;
            year = _year;
        }

        date() :day(0), month(0), year(0){}
    }date;


    template <class _Clock,
        class _Time = typename _Clock::time,
            class _Date = typename _Clock::date>
    class time_point
    {
    public:
        typedef _Clock clock;
        typedef _Time time;
        typedef _Date date;

        time_point(const time& otherTime, const date& otherDate)
        {
            _MyTime = otherTime;
            _MyDate = otherDate;
        }

        time get_time() const
        {
            return (_MyTime);
        }

        date get_date() const
        {
            return (_MyDate);
        }

    private:
        _Time _MyTime;
        _Date _MyDate;
    };
}

struct utc_clock
{
    typedef unsigned long long time;
    typedef tc::date date;
    typedef tc::time_point<utc_clock> time_point;
public:
    static time_point now()
    {
        SYSTEMTIME systime;
        GetSystemTime(&systime);

        time_t cur_time = time(0);
        struct tm *time_buf = localtime(&cur_time);

        time t = (((time_buf->tm_sec + (time_buf->tm_min * 60) + (time_buf->tm_hour * 3600)) * 1000) + systime.wMilliseconds) * 1000ULL;

        tc::date d((unsigned int)systime.wDay, (unsigned int)systime.wMonth, (unsigned int)systime.wYear);

        return time_point(t, d);
    }

    static time to_micro(const time_point& t)
    {
        return t.get_time();
    }

    static time to_mili(const time_point& t)
    {
        return to_micro(t) / 1000;
    }

    static time to_sec(const time_point& t)
    {
        return to_mili(t) / 1000;
    }

    static time to_min(const time_point& t)
    {
        return to_sec(t) / 60;
    }

    static time to_hour(const time_point& t)
    {
        return to_min(t) / 60;
    }

    static char * to_utc_time_str(const time_point& t)
    {
        char *str = new char[100];

        sprintf(str, "%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d", to_hour(t), to_min(t), to_sec(t), to_mili(t), to_micro(t));
        return str;
    }

    static char * to_utc_date_str(const time_point& t)
    {
        char *str = new char[100];

        sprintf(str, "%02d.%02d.%04d", t.get_date().day, t.get_date().month, t.get_date().year);
        return str;
    }
};
```

The usage goes like that:

```
int main()
{

    tc::time_point<utc_clock> t = utc_clock::now();

    char * str = utc_clock::to_utc_date_str(t);

    unsigned long long micro, mili, second;
    unsigned long long s;

    micro = utc_clock::to_micro(t);
    mili = utc_clock::to_mili(t);
    second = utc_clock::to_sec(t);

    s = micro + mili;  // this is not good, need to use type-safe 
                       //handler on return time, or have a converter to allow it.

    cout << "Micro: " << micro << endl;
    cout << "Mili: " << mili << endl;
    cout << "Seconds: " << second << endl;

    cout << "UTC Date is: " << str << endl;

    getchar();

}
```

There are few things I think I can improve in my code, but don't know how to implement it.

1. all the function in `to_micro`, `to_mili`, `to_sec` ... etc can be written
   in otherway using operator overloading maybe? for example I can have `'sc'` operator that can convert to seconds based on the received time. `sc(1000)` // 1000 is in mili, will convert it automatically to 1.
2. I want to make sure that doing arithmetical operation on different kind of times(mili/seconds/micro) is avoided. I'd be happy to get a direction over it.

Any other suggestions/idea will be greatly welcomed

Comment: Welcome to code review. Does the code to be reviewed work as expected? You indicate that there are issues, Do these issue affect how the code runs?

Comment: @pacmaninbw thank you. The code runs without bugs. I have issued all the problem that might occur and that I want to avoid. which of them was not clear? maybe I need to explain better

Answer (score 2):

### Fix all Warnings and Errors

During development it is a best practice to get all warning messages as well as all error messages. Warning messages can indicate hidden bugs in the code. For most C++ compilers the `-wall` switch will provide all warnings. I am building using Visual Studio 2019 Professional and there are many warnings presented during the build:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: timelibrary2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>timelibrary2.cpp
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): warning C4477: 'sprintf' : format string '%02d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'utc_clock::time'
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%lld' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%I64d' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): warning C4477: 'sprintf' : format string '%02d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 2 has type 'utc_clock::time'
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%lld' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%I64d' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): warning C4477: 'sprintf' : format string '%02d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 3 has type 'utc_clock::time'
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%lld' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%I64d' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): warning C4477: 'sprintf' : format string '%03d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 4 has type 'utc_clock::time'
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%lld' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%I64d' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): warning C4477: 'sprintf' : format string '%03d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 5 has type 'utc_clock::time'
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%lld' in the format string
>   1>D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\timelibrary2\timelibrary2.cpp(107,16): message : consider using '%I64d' in the format string
>   1>timelibrary2.vcxproj -> D:\ProjectsNfwsi\CodeReview\timelibrary2\Debug\timelibrary2.exe
>   1>Done building project "timelibrary2.vcxproj".
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

The above warnings are all on line 107 which is this line:

```
        sprintf(str, "%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d:%03d", to_hour(t), to_min(t), to_sec(t), to_mili(t), to_micro(t));
```

There is also a warning in the IDE about this line:

```
        time t = (((time_buf->tm_sec + (time_buf->tm_min * 60) + (time_buf->tm_hour * 3600)) * 1000) + systime.wMilliseconds) * 1000ULL;
```

This warning is `Arithmetic Overflow`, which can indeed create errors or bugs.

### Avoid `using namespace std;`

While it is not in the code under review, it is apparent from the code in `main()` that the `using namespace std;` is in the code.

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

### struct utc_clock

In the declaration of `struct utc_clock` there is the `public:` declaration, this is not necessary since by default all contents of a struct are public.

It is not clear why all the functions in the struct are declared as `static`. It means while many instances of the utc_clock struct may be instantiated, they all refer to one instance of each function.

If the utc_clock struct is being use to convert the system up time to utc, it might be good to add a function `to_days` as well, since some systems may be up for days, weeks or months.

### Declare and Initialize Variables at the Same Time

A good practice in C++ is to initialize the variables when they are declared. C++ does not automatically initialize variables as some other languages do. Each declaration and initialization should be in it's own statement, on its own line, this makes it easier to find and edit the variable declaration and initialization.

Instead of

```
    unsigned long long micro, mili, second;

    micro = utc_clock::to_micro(t);
    mili = utc_clock::to_mili(t);
    second = utc_clock::to_sec(t);
```

it would be better to declare and initialize like this

```
    unsigned long long micro = utc_clock::to_micro(t);
    unsigned long long mili = utc_clock::to_mili(t);
    unsigned long long second = utc_clock::to_sec(t);

    unsigned long long s = micro + mili;
```

### Unused Variables

In the `main()` function, the variable `s` is declared and assigned a value but it is never referenced. It would better if the variable `s` wasn't declared or initialized.

### Initialization of Private Variables in a Constructor

It is possible and generally desired to private variables in a class outside the body of the constructor. This can be accomplished using the `{}` operator, so instead of

```
        time_point(const time& otherTime, const date& otherDate)
        {
            _MyTime = otherTime;
            _MyDate = otherDate;
        }
```

use

```
        time_point(const time& otherTime, const date& otherDate)
        : _MyTime{otherTime}, _MyDate{otherDate}
        {
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. noted everything. what about the type-safety issue regarding the returned type?(to_sec/to_micro etc..) how can I solve this?